# How to revert the demo sites to English? (Or change to another language)

Tags: localisation, demo-site

The demo site is in Russian (or Chinese or French -- or any language you don't read fluently), how can I switch it to English *(or my preferred language)*?

As the demo sites are periodically reset to a default state (in English), waiting is an option, but not the fastest one.

Answer (score 5):

You can change the language in

Administer > Localization > Languages, Currency, Locations

and change the default language (first field) to English (United States)

However, as the site is in a different language, it might be hard to find (the url is civicrm/admin/setting/localization), so here are the direct links:

- [Drupal](http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/admin/setting/localization?reset=1)
- [Joomla](http://joomla.demo.civicrm.org/administrator/?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/admin/setting/localization&reset=1)
- [Wordpress](http://wp46.demo.civicrm.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/admin/setting/localization&reset=1)

Comment: and once you have changed it, another user might set it back to Chinese....

Comment: The instruction works as well to switch to chinese. If 1.4 billion chinese work on it together, I think we will have chinese as the default language soon ;)

Answer (score 1):

Trying to change the language can sometimes lead to a 'race' condition where you and another user are just changing it back and forth. Not nice. I think it's fine to change it once, since the user with a different language preference/need might be done.

But if the language is changed out from under you the polite thing to do, at least in my Canadian view, is to switch to using a different CMS demo site, or come back in 15 or 30 minutes.

Comment: Good point Joe.

Comment: not sure what stats are kept on people usng the demo site. if it gets busy enough it may warrant extending the civi infrastructure to having one version of demos that is set to english (of some variety) and another for non-english to cut down on the site getting switched around while people are trying it

Comment: I find it happens fairly regularly.